# What is the minimum number of data points required for kernel density estimation?

Tags: density-function, unsupervised-learning, kernel-smoothing

What is the minimum number of data points required for a kernel density estimation to be considered non-misleading/acceptable/adequate?

Is there a some rule based on how dispersed the data is?

For example, if the inter-quartile range is "small enough", do you need less points than if the inter-quartile range is "larger"?

Alternatively, you may have encountered a situation where a certain size of dataset was "enough" or "not enough" and can share the reasons why KDE worked/didn't work in that specific case?

Criteria to assess accuracy: 
If you had two samplesfrom the same population and you do a KDE on each one, then the two resulting densities are very similar.

Comment: Well, you can't do it at all with fewer than one point. You *can* do it with one (though it may not be very meaningful or useful). Therefore, one point is the absolute minimum required.

Comment: ...In other words, I believe you meant to ask "what is the minimum number of data points required for a kernel density estimation to be considered non-misleading/acceptable/adequate (something like that), based on accumulated experience up to now?" Remember it is only our words that connect us here - no personal history, no facial expressions, no body language, no "silently understood" implied meanings. For the benefit of all, we must try to be _very_ exact and precise in how we formulate our questions (and answers).

Comment: Note that questions relating to adequacy, acceptability, and so on, require details about the criteria being applied to conclude adequacy, etc ... or it's just personal opinion based on personal preferences and individual experience of situations likely different from the next persons situational experiences (as well as being off-topic on CV).

Comment: If you want to estimate quantiles, use quantile estimation, not kernel density estimation. If you want to estimate the distribution function, similar remarks apply.

Comment: Hi, @NickCox. Thanks for your comments! I hadn't seen your post even though I did search for questions related to mine.

Comment: I just don't entirely agree with what you said in terms of estimating quantiles and not the density/distribution. Both sample quantiles and KDE are biased for finite samples. And I have evidence that as the sample size increases, KDE-based quantiles seem to outperform sample quantiles.

The crucial question for me is what to do when the sample size is "small". Is the Harrell-Davis quantile estimator the way to go? And what does "small" mean?

Comment: Previous question was not mine. I'd be interested to see your evidence (published paper?) on various estimates of quantiles. My statement is based on instinct that getting at the density function is a very indirect way to get at quantiles, and so fallible. A serious way to get evidence is simulation, but that often leaves barely touched the question of performance with real and quirky datasets.

Comment: It's not a paper. Computational experiments (Monte Carlo simulations) with KDE functions in R and comparing the estimated quantiles (from KDE and empirical) with the "exact" ones provided by the distribution package. There are PDF- and CDF-based methods to estimate quantiles (different R packages use different methods). But for small sample sizes, KDE doesn't seem to be a good idea. Still curious about recommendations for sample sizes. :)

Comment: Sorry to come to the discussion quite late, but what exactly do you mean by 'minimum sample size'? Minimum for what purpose? I think Nick is right in suggesting that the intended application is relevant.

Comment: I'm curious to know if there is any rule or justification for choosing the minimum sample size to obtain something like minimum accuracy.

For example, someone proposed a rule for the B parameter in bootstrap confidence intervals:

Donald W. K. Andrews and Moshe Buchinsky
On the Number of Bootstrap Repetitions for BCa Confidence Intervals
Econometric Theory, Vol. 18, No. 4 (Aug., 2002), pp. 962-984

Comment: I found some discussion on section 4.5.2 (pages 93 and 94) in Silverman's book. See Table 4.2: http://books.google.com/books?id=e-xsrjsL7WkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=4.5.2&f=false

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the book "Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis, Bernard. W. Silverman, CRC ,1986" there is a chapter "Required sample size for given accuracy" where a sample size required is given to get the relative MSE at zero not greater that 0.1. I enclose the table presented there. [image]

Comment: I would add that these sample size estimates are optimistic: the density being estimated is assumed known and, more importantly, the chosen density is well behaved from the pov of KDE.

Comment: @artgram: Thank you for the answer! How do we define the mean squared error while estimating the kernel density?