# Minimum sample size for kernel density estimation

Tags: sample-size, kernel-smoothing

I was wondering if there is any recommendation for a "decent" minimum sample size when estimating the density/distribution/quantiles of a random variable using KDE. Is it always the case that "the more data the better"?

Comment: Already asked (but not answered) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76948/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-data-points-required-for-kernel-density-estimation The absence of answers perhaps reflects a feeling equivalent to your last question; and also that complicated (e.g. skewed, long-tailed, granular, multimodal) underlying distributions will need even more data than simple ones. One thing you can always do is try estimation with a smaller subsample to judge the extent of deterioration in estimation quality.